# Question about MongoDB from a SQL user

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have very interested in using MongoDB it seems awesome. But I'm from a totally different school : relational databases.

So now I'm wondering how would this case works with MongoDB:

Say, I have a table filled with brands and I have another table filled with products.

Each products will have a brand. This is very simple to understand but I still don't get how would this works with MongoDB?

I mean, would I have to repeat the brand each time I add a product? Can I do some kind of relations?

Thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: check the answer by sriehl. that i believe is the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Insert brands
2. Insert insert products (with brands)
3. Query it

Preparation:

- Download http://www.mongodb.org/downloads
- On Windows create dir `c:\data\db\` (the default dir, don't care much about it now)
- Run mongod (it will run a server)
- Run mongo (it will run a client and use default test database)

Brands:

```
db.things.save({'name': 'Ford'});
db.things.save({'name': 'Mitsubishi'});
```

Products:

```
db.things.save({'brand': 'Ford', 'name': 'Mustang'});
db.things.save({'brand': 'Ford', 'name': 'Falcon'});
db.things.save({'brand': 'Mitsubishi', 'name': 'Delica'});
db.things.save({'brand': 'Mitsubishi', 'name': 'L300'});
```

Querying:

```
db.things.find();
db.things.find({'brand': 'Ford'});
db.things.find({'brand': 'Mitsubishi'});
```

// I just learned this (incl. downloading etc) almost before the first answer was posted from [tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial) and [manual](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Manual) in general. Nice experience :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if, I need to rename one brand? Does it create many entry of the brand throughout the database or it only references it?

Comment: Rename: `db.things.update({"name": "L300" }, {"brand": "Mitsubishi", "name": "L300 4WD"});` I suppose it keeps just one entry for one object and references it. 
Every single entry contains ObjectId "_id" which seems same all the time for me so I suppose it updates this entry instead of removing and inserting it.

Comment: @Tom: Tom, download it and play with it, use my examples as starting point, copy & paste them to mongo command line (multiple rows allowed!). You'll understand it better, highly recommended :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! On http://www.mongodb.org/ you can actually try everything on their javascript console! It's awesome and now I get it! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to set it up similar to this:

```
{'brand':'brand one', 'products':
                       [{'product name':'a fine product','price':'$50'},
                        {'product name':'yet another fine product','price':'$20'}]
},
{'brand':'brand two', 'products':
                       [{'product name':'brand two product','price':'$10'}]
}
```

In this case you only have one 'table' with all the information you need on the products (including brand). I have only done some experimenting with mongodb so I'm not sure how this would scale.

It is a different way of thinking from a relational DB and a nosql solution shouldn't be used in all cases.

Comment: Oh! okay so what you're telling me is my ""relations"" should be in the way I "align" my models? From the highest to the lowest so it would make something like this:
Blog->Author->Article->Comments.

It's pretty logic! So I always have everything I need to use... Thanks for the help :)